# Printers Localhost - Can add Printer can't ping the IP address

Tags: networking, wireless, printing

I'm having trouble installing my printer to Ubuntu 14.04

The printer is: Fuji Xerox Docuprint P265 dw

It's connected to my wifi router and has IP=169.254.12.34

The printer shows up using the Pirnts - LocalHost > add printer

[image]

But then the drivers wont install, it hangs on installing "gutenprint"

[image]

Also, nothing shows up when I try pinging the printer, even though it shows up in the add printer dialogue (shown above):

```
ping 169.254.12.34
```

I've been trying to follow this guide [printing debugging in ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems)

Any help you could give would be appreciated.

**Solved**

For anyone reading this in a similar situation. It turns out that my printer had a static IP address, which was out of the router's subnet or something.

To fix this, I changed IP using the printer's lcd

**My IP = 10.0.0.8**

**Old Wrong Printer IP = 169.254.12.34**

**New Printer IP = 10.0.0.64**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious you need to install the `gutenprint` driver. even though you can see the printer but still you need to install this driver since you stuck on the dialogue showing that.

Search and download your printer driver from [here](http://www.openprinting.org/driver/gutenprint/), then I think you can use it normally.