# add printer: no printer found at its address

Tags: networking, printing, epson

since a few days I'm reading a lot of questions on askubuntu ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637447/printers-localhost-can-add-printer-cant-ping-the-ip-address), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345104/how-to-connect-to-a-wlan-printer), or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328874/how-to-print-using-wireless-to-a-canon-mg6150/328893#328893) for instance) and try to fix my printer problem. However, I cannot find a solution.

I would love to connect the printer with my ubuntu 18.04 machine using wifi. My computer and the printer are properly connected to the same wlan. However, if I click 'add printer' in the settings, the printer is not found.

From the front panel of the printer I can print its ip address. However, if I ping the address from my ubuntu 18.04 machine the destination is unreachable. If I add a new printer by specifying the host address (which is the ip of the printer), I receive the message: "No printer was found at that address".

Publishing shared printers on my network and printing from the internet is enabled.

I appreciate every suggestion and can provide any additional information needed. Feel free to ask.

Cheers

P.S. I don't know if its relevant but I already installed the same printer model (EPSON ET-2750) on my machine at a different place with different wlan without problems using the 'add printer' button. Because I was so satisfied, I now got the same printer for myself. Could it be that the information from the old printer hinder the new installation?

Comment: The first thing to solve is the failed ping. Do you have a firewall running on your computer?

Comment: No, I don't have a firewall

Comment: What are the IP addresses, Default Gateways and netmasks fo the printer / PC?

Comment: PC: IP 192.168.1.82, Mask 255.255.255.0, Gateway 192.168.1.254. Printer: IP 192.168.1.85, Mask 255.255.255.0, Gateway 192.168.1.254